# Connect Boxes in Table Cells by Arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tabularx, layout

I am trying to create a table containing in its three columns:

1. A top-to-bottom flowchart
2. Graphs
3. Figures

[image: Intended Layout]

I have drawn the steps in the flowchart using a framed `parbox`:

```
\fbox{\parbox{20mm}{
    \centering
    Text
}}
```

To connect the boxes, I tried using using manually set coordinates with the tikzmark package.

**But how can I make sure the arrows are:**

1. Centered below/above boxes
2. Connected to the frame of the boxes
   ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}


% Table Setup
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[2]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering text in X column

\begin{document}
\minipage{\textwidth}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c|X|X| }
        \hline
            Process Step
        &
            Relevant Parameters
        &
            Visual Representation
        \\
        \hline
            \fbox{\parbox{20mm}{
                \centering
                Wire
                Bonding
            }} \tikzmark{a}
        &
            Figure
        &
            Image
        \\
        \hline
            \fbox{\parbox{20mm}{
                \centering
                Phosphor
                Deposition
            }} \tikzmark{b}
        &
            Figure
        &
            Image
        \\
        \hline
        
    \end{tabularx}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [->] ({pic cs:a}) to ({pic cs:b});
    \end{tikzpicture}


\endminipage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, but in order to at least make the code compilable, use `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % for the valign=c option

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}


\begin{document}
\minipage{\textwidth}

    \begin{tabular}{ |0c|0c|0c| }
        \hline
            Process Step
        &
            Relevant Parameters
        &
            Visual Representation
        \\
        \hline
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding  box.center), remember picture]
          \node (A) [draw=black,text width=2cm, align=center]  {Wire Bonding};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
            \includegraphics[width=4cm, valign=c]{example-image}
        &
            \includegraphics[width=4cm, valign=c]{example-image}
        \\
        \hline
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding  box.center), remember picture]
          \node (B) [draw=black,text width=2cm, align=center]{Phosphor Deposition};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        &
            \includegraphics[width=4cm, valign=c]{example-image}
        &
            \includegraphics[width=4cm, valign=c]{example-image}
        \\
        \hline
        
    \end{tabular}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, black, remember picture]
\draw[ultra thick, ->] (A.south) -- (B.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\endminipage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this meet the requirement--I have added a row between the boxes so that the arrow can be seen --also you can experiment with the placement of the arrow by adjusting the coordinates `(-1,0)` -- hline has been commented out for a clean table you can put them back if desired

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|X|X|}
%        \hline
            Process Step &
            Relevant Parameters &
            Visual Representation\\
%        \hline
            \fbox{\parbox{20mm}{
                \centering
                Wire Bonding
            }} \tikzmark{a} &
            Figure &
            Image\\
%        \hline
&&\\
            \fbox{\parbox{20mm}{
                \centering
                Phosphor Deposition}} \tikzmark{b} &
            Figure &
            Image\\
        \hline
        \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [->,ultra thick, red] ($({pic cs:a})+(-1,0)$) -- ($({pic cs:b})+(-1,0)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Optionally use the following tikzpicture for a side going arrow--

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw ($(pic cs:a)+(-2pt,0pt) $) edge[bend left=60, -latex,  red,ultra thick] 
($(pic cs:b)+(-2pt,0pt)$) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]